# Why do the return value of the first and second calls of image field accessor differ?

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

The first call of the accessor of the image field of a `BlobWrapper` returns None and the second call returns a `BlobWrapper`. Some hint?

```python
In [1]: id = app.Plone.invokeFactory('Image', 'myimage', title='MyImage')

In [2]: image=app.Plone[id]

In [3]: blobWrapper=image.getBlobWrapper()

In [4]: accessor=blobWrapper.getField('image').getAccessor(blobWrapper)

In [5]: accessor()

In [6]: accessor()
Out[6]: <plone.app.blob.field.BlobWrapper at 0xa35a194>
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but probably because you have created an Image content with empty image field. Maybe the first call create an empty blob while it have nothing to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAccessor` method of the field takes the object in this case your `ATImage instance` as parameter not a `blobWrapper instance`

```python
>>> accessor = image.getField('image').getAccessor(image)
>>> accessor()
<plone.app.blob.field.BlobWrapper object at 0x1050446e0>
```

Check [this github link](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/master/Products/Archetypes/Field.py#L681)

```python
security.declarePublic('getAccessor')
def getAccessor(self, instance):
    """Return the accessor method for getting data out of this
    field"""
    if self.accessor:
        return getattr(instance, self.accessor, None)
    return None
```

UPDATE:
Explenation why the first call of the accessor is `None` and second not.

I has something to do with the magic's of Products.Archetypes.
If you pass the BlobWrapper instance instead of a ATImage instance, the following happens:

**First call:**
At some point the `get` method of Archetypes ObjectField gets called, See https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/master/Products/Archetypes/Field.py#L785

It catches the AttributeError (`AttributeError: Attribut...'image'`), which btw. usually happens if you add a new Field to a ContentType, because the BlobWrapper instance has no Attribute `image` (The ATImage would have this attribute).

Then it initializes your BlobWrapper like a new field on the ATImage. 
This persists some crap on your Blobwrapper instance, which you don't want :-)
The return value is `None`, see https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/master/Products/Archetypes/Field.py#L803

**Second call:**
Since the first call did some modifications to your BlobWrapper instance, the second call works and returns the correct value.
https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/master/Products/Archetypes/Field.py#L785

Technically the first call initializes an `AnnotationStorage` on your BlobWrapper instance.

```
> /Users/maethu/.buildout/eggs-cache/Products.Archetypes-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/Products/Archetypes/Storage/annotation.py(62)get()
-> def get(self, name, instance, **kwargs):
(Pdb) l
 57             """Clean up data in set method
 58             """
 59             raise NotImplementedError
 60
 61         security.declarePrivate('get')
 62  ->     def get(self, name, instance, **kwargs):
 63             ann = getAnnotation(instance)
 64             value = ann.getSubkey(self._key, subkey=name, default=_marker)
 65             if value is _marker:
 66                 if self._migrate:
 67                     value = self._migration(name, instance, **kwargs)
(Pdb) name
'image'
(Pdb) instance
<plone.app.blob.field.BlobWrapper object at 0x10d4042a8>
(Pdb) getAnnotation(instance)
{'Archetypes.storage.AnnotationStorage-image': <plone.app.blob.field.BlobWrapper object at 0x10d430a28>}
```

I really think you should not do this :-)

If I got something wrong pls correct... it's kinda hard to understand this Archetypes behaviour.

Comment: Yes. I undestand this. But why does the behavior differs on `blobWrapper.getField('image').getAccessor(blobWrapper)`? I would expect both (first and second) calls return the same. As it is the case with `image.getField('image').getAccessor(image)` and `blobWrapper.getField('image').getAccessor(image)`.

Comment: @wolfrevo I updated my answer. I dove in to Archetypes, now I feel a little bit dirty :-)

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your in detail explanation. From a best practice point of view I'd expect the first call to do all the necessary modifications and to return the correct value. IMHO this is a bug.
1+ and tnx for your efforts. I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: @wolfrevo yes imho it's a bug too, at least it should work as expected, or fail :-) As you may know, you could use Dexterity based contenttypes. DX works without the magic's of Archetypes.